# What is Google Chrome's block/allow pattern syntax?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, blocking, cookies, blacklist

I'm looking for documentation describing Google Chrome's glob/wildcard/pattern syntax used in block/allow lists for content settings.

If you're using Chrome, these settings pages are accessible via urls like:

`chrome://settings/content/javascript`

`chrome://settings/content/cookies`

There are several other pages that use the same url matching syntax. When you click "Add", the form displays the example text, `[*.]example.com`. The square brackets appear to be necessary when using the wildcard pattern, as omitting them results in the message, `Not a valid web address`.

Official documentation or source code would be nice, but a plain old BNF is ideal.

I have found two related pages that describe url pattern matching in Chrome, but neither of them apply to this case. Please don't reference them unless it turns out that I've misunderstood their relevance (neither document the required square brackets):

1. https://www.chromium.org/administrators/url-blacklist-filter-format
2. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From some testing it's like this:

Doesn't match subdomains automatically, unless you prefix [*.], which seems to be the only allowed wildcard construct. Further you can optionally prefix the exact URI scheme and suffix the exact port.

```
For: https://www.whatismybrowser.com
    ❌ whatismybrowser.com
    ✔ www.whatismybrowser.com
    ✔ [*.]whatismybrowser.com
    ✔ https://www.whatismybrowser.com
    ✔ https://[*.]whatismybrowser.com
    ✔ https://[*.]whatismybrowser.com:443
    ✔ [*.]whatismybrowser.com:443
    ✔ *://www.whatismybrowser.com -> removes scheme prefix
    ✔ [*.]whatismybrowser.com/ -> removes path suffix
    ❌ http://www.whatismybrowser.com -> as expected
    ❌ www.whatismybrowser.tld
    ❌ www.whatismybrowser.* or [.*] -> invalid input
    ❌ foo.[*.]whatismybrowser.com -> invalid input
```

Comment: Would a subdomain like **foo.bar.whatismybrowser.com** be matched with **[\*.]whatismybrowser.com** ? In other words, does **[\*.]** match multiple parts or a single one before the dot?

Answer (score 2):

I initially had the same behavior but `[*.]example.com` is the correct syntax and it works, after i have copy and paste the adress from [HERE](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Now i can use every url, maybe it's a bug.

Comment: I've already figured as much, but it seems like there should be much more to the syntax, or at least a definitive resource that's not on the help page for cookies, since this is used elsewhere.